# ListView com altura dinâmica(sem scroll)

Tags: android, android-layout

Considerando a seguinte estrutura:

> ListView (1) > Adapter (1) > ListView (2) > Adapter (2)

Preciso de colocar uma listview dentro de um adapter, e nessa list view podem haver vários outros adapters.

O Adapter(1) dentro da ListView(1) precisa conter uma ListView(2) e dentro dessa lista preciso de Adapters(2) com alturas de acordo com o seu conteúdo.

O já tentei de tudo que vi em tutoriais e nada adiantou, sempre acontece a mesma coisa. O Adapter(1) fica com o tamanho fixo, e a ListView(2) cria a rolagem, ela não fica full em altura para reajustar o Adapter(1).

Deixo abaixo uma imagem com exemplo e legenda, e agradeço se alguém puder me informar como posso estar fazendo essa lista.
Obrigado.

[image: Mockup de como ficaria a listagem]

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa calcular a altura da sua listView de acordo com o número de items, é isso?

Eu uso esse código:

```
public void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();
    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

        if(listItem != null){
            // This next line is needed before you call measure or else you won't get measured height at all. The listitem needs to be drawn first to know the height.
            listItem.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

        }
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Ai basta você chamá-lo, assim:

```
setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(instancia_da_sua_list_view);
```

Comment: Olá Leandro, perfeito entendi a lógica porém a meu adapter(1) tá pegando 100% da tela, ele não tá ficando proporcional ao listview

Comment: Voce deixa os conteudos com wrapcontent?

Comment: Isso, pode deixar a altura no wrap_content, esse método vai definir a altura pra vc, só lembre-se de chama-lo depois que o listview for populado.

Comment: chame ele depois do lstView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: lstView é meu listview 2